# 'SOCK_RAW' option in 'socket' system call

Tags: sockets, unix, networking

I am new to socket programming and trying my hand on it on Linux machine (ubuntu)
I am unable to understand the option 'SOCK_RAW' and want to learn about it.
What is the significance of the 'SOCK_RAW' option in 'socket' system call ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Raw mode (by socket type `SOCK_RAW`) is basically there to allow you to bypass some of the way that your computer handles TCP/IP. Rather than going through the normal layers of encapsulation/decapsulation that the TCP/IP stack on the kernel does, you just pass the packet to the application that needs it. No TCP/IP processing -- so it's not a processed packet, it's a raw packet. The application that's using the packet is now responsible for stripping off the headers, analyzing the packet, all the stuff that the TCP/IP stack in the kernel normally does for you.

For more information see the following links:

- [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw) for raw socket man page
- you can fine a good example [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html)
- [here](https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/) there is a tutorial